# Android Widget Update service, multiple onclick listeners

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-service, android-broadcast

I have the following widget service which updates a text view when I click on my one button.

UpdateWidgetService:

```
ipublic class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

private static final String LOG = "widgetService";
private static final String MyOnClick1 = "myOnClickTag1";
private static final String MyOnClick2 = "myOnClickTag2";
private static final String MyOnClick3 = "myOnClickTag3";

static LocationClient mLocationClient;

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    Log.i(LOG, "Called and started");

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
    Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        // create some random data
        int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
        // Set the text
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview_gpscoords, "Random: " + String.valueOf(number));

        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);

        clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_dissarm, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    stopSelf();
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

MyWidget Provider:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String LOG = "de.vogella.android.widget.example";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    // Build the intent to call the service
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

    // Update the widgets via the service
    context.startService(intent);
        }
}
```

android manifest:

```
<!-- Widget -->
    <receiver
        android:name="widget.MyWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="My Widget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />                
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- Services -->
    <service android:name="widget.UpdateWidgetService" >
    </service>
```

Now my issue is that, how do I determine which button gets clicked? I have 4 buttons on my widget and I want to differentiate between which ones are clicked? In my example the intent for the buttons onclick is `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE`  Im thinking I need to change that some how?

What is the correct way to go about doing this?

Ultimately my buttons are each going to make a webcall, this is why I am using the service, as the web call can take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your UpdateWidgetService.java as the code below.

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

private static final String LOG = "widgetService";

// my changes - part 1 - beginning
private static final String BUTTON_ONE_CLICKED = "com.yourpackage.BUTTON_ONE_CLICKED";
private static final String BUTTON_TWO_CLICKED = "com.yourpackage.BUTTON_TWO_CLICKED";
private static final String BUTTON_THREE_CLICKED = "com.yourpackage.BUTTON_THREE_CLICKED";
private static final String BUTTON_FOUR_CLICKED = "com.yourpackage.BUTTON_FOUR_CLICKED";
// my changes - part 1 - end


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    Log.i(LOG, "Called and started");
    
    // my changes - part 2 - beginning
    if(BUTTON_ONE_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // do what should be done if button One has been clicked
    }
    if(BUTTON_TWO_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // do what should be done if button Two has been clicked
    }
    if(BUTTON_THREE_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // do what should be done if button Three has been clicked
    }
    if(BUTTON_FOUR_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // do what should be done if button Four has been clicked
    }
    // my changes - part 2 - end

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
    Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        // create some random data
        int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
        // Set the text
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview_gpscoords, "Random: " + String.valueOf(number));
        
        // my changes - part 3 - beginning
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        
        Intent buttonOneIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        Intent buttonTwoIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        Intent buttonThreeIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        Intent buttonFourIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        
        // set action
        buttonOneIntent.setAction(BUTTON_ONE_CLICKED);
        buttonTwoIntent.setAction(BUTTON_TWO_CLICKED);
        buttonThreeIntent.setAction(BUTTON_THREE_CLICKED);
        buttonFourIntent.setAction(BUTTON_FOUR_CLICKED);
        
        // put widgetId
        buttonOneIntent.putExtra("widgetId", widgetId);
        buttonTwoIntent.putExtra("widgetId", widgetId);
        buttonThreeIntent.putExtra("widgetId", widgetId);
        buttonFourIntent.putExtra("widgetId", widgetId);
        
        // make these intents unique to avoid collisions
        buttonOneIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("webcall_widget://buttonone/widgetid"), String.valueOf(widgetId)));
        buttonTwoIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("webcall_widget://buttontwo/widgetid"), String.valueOf(widgetId)));
        buttonThreeIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("webcall_widget://buttonthree/widgetid"), String.valueOf(widgetId)));
        buttonFourIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("webcall_widget://buttonfour/widgetid"), String.valueOf(widgetId)));
        
        // pending intents
        PendingIntent buttonOnePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, buttonOneIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent buttonTwoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, buttonTwoIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent buttonThreePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, buttonThreeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent buttonFourPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, buttonFourIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        
        // register onClickListeners to your buttons
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, buttonOnePendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_two, buttonTwoPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_three, buttonThreePendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_four, buttonFourPendingIntent);
        // my changes - part 3 - end

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    stopSelf();
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

If something is unclear do not hesitate and ask me please.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but now doesn't my widget provider only receive broadcast intents with the action `<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />` ? now I will be changing the action and therefore the service wont get called.

Comment: Oh Wait I think I see what yu are doing. Your intent is accessing the service directly, its not going through the update broadcast which the widgetproivider receives. The widget service receives the intent directly. If I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Zapnologica Yes, you are right and understand correctly. I hope that my answer helped you enough.