# Multiple PendingIntents for a single widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I have an app widget which contains 4 buttons and logic of these buttons (what they should do when they are clicked) are different. I have used the following pattern for assigning `PendingIntent`s to them

```
/* for button 1 */
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1000 + widgetId,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

/* for button 2 */
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2000 + widgetId,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

/* for button 3 */
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 3000 + widgetId,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

/* for button 4 */
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 4000 + widgetId,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And this code works fine. But I think this is not a good practice. I also tried using Fill-in Template mechanism but it wont work.

Can any one please tell me what is the best practice for assigning multiple different intents to multiple buttons on a single widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23244505/3343299)) to another question can help you. If you need more information or something is not clear don't hesitate and ask.

Here is only a part of mentioned answer:

```
// set action
buttonOneIntent.setAction(BUTTON_ONE_CLICKED);
buttonTwoIntent.setAction(BUTTON_TWO_CLICKED);
buttonThreeIntent.setAction(BUTTON_THREE_CLICKED);
buttonFourIntent.setAction(BUTTON_FOUR_CLICKED);
// ......
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, your solution also works, but considering an action for each buttons in my opinion is not as good as the ideal solution. However I consider a +1 for you

Comment: @ABFORCE Thank you for your acknowledgement.